# Performing push notification in parse programmatically

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Hello i'm creating an application that involves users to invite other users to an event and doing this in android. i'm using parse as a BaaS. i saw parse provides a push notification and this can use a console log. I was wondering if this could de done programmatically without using the console where a users sends an invite to all users in the table. UserB can accept or reject the invitation UserA sent out. Could this be done programmatically without involving the console and if so could someone please show with an example i will really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do that using cloud code which is javascript (platform independent)

```
Parse.Push.send({
    channels: [ "channel_name" ],
    data: {
        alert: "Alert message"
    }
}, {
    success: function () {
        response.success(Push was sent");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        response.error("Could not send push " + error)
    }
});
```

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications

Comment: so basically i have the userA send their event invitation to the cloude code which broad cast the messages to all users in the table

Comment: I did use push notification but from the console and not using cloud code...so you gotta read the docs....

Comment: i wanted to do it programmatically without using the console. A userA sends out notifications to all users

Comment: yes programmatically...its all there in the docs...the link I provided...go through that